# kivy or something else for android UI

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, sl4a

I am learning to program (python 3.x) and was wondering what would be best to learn for making android apps/games. I dont know anything about UI really but have heard that kivy? Is on android. Is that worth learning or should i use something else.
Thanks

Edit: 
I am using sl4a and py34a on my android device.

Comment: Actually, with a layer pyjnius (https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) you can access Android sensors directly from Python

Answer (score 2):

Kivy is good, and will run on Android, but you can't make Android apps with it. It has no way of interacting with the Android API. You can run a kivy app on the device, but can not read sensors or anything like that. They have a project called pyjnius, which allows you to access Java classes from Python, but not with Python3, and it's not very easy to use unless you know Java.

You have SL4A installed, so you can use web technology to do UIs, including games, which can be rendered on the device using webviews. That said, Kivy is a much more mature and well maintained project.

Comment: You are right that Kivy does not allow you to natively query the sensors, but it is not as bad as you make it sound, IMHO.  -- The Droidspace project's github space says that the project is "dead". So I'd go for Kivy and Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm loving kivy. The irony is, that I found this topic here looking for help with python 3. Python 2 works perfectly, but 3 is still being made compatible. Other than that Kivy is great for beginner coders. Especially, because you don't have to code the complex stuff.